# Lorenz attractor as a 2-dimensional set in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: dynamical-systems

Why is it correct to say that Lorenz attractor is a two-dimensional set in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it is incorrect, or just a vague statement?

Comment: It's hard to see, but Lorenz' attractor has some "thickness". While the dynamics on Lorenz' attractor can be approximated by some 2D systems, it is by itself not 2-dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of *two-dimensional,* more precisely your notion of *dimension:*

- [Topological dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_dimension) are 1. (There may be some notion of the topology of the attractor according to which it is two-dimensional, but not more than this.)
- [Fractal dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension) are strictly larger than 2 (also see the [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2838966/65502)).
- If you look for the lowest-dimensional manifold that contains the attractor, this needs to be larger than two since you cannot have a continuous-time chaotic dynamics on a two-dimensional manifold: You need at least one dimension for temporal evolution, one for stretching, and one for folding.

Note that the last two points apply to all chaotic attractors of continuous-time systems.

Answer (score 4):

No.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system#Analysis) says that Hausdorff dimension of the Lorenz attractor is estimated to be $2.06 \pm 0.01$, for the classical parameters $\rho = 28$, $\sigma = 10$, $\beta = 8/3$.

Comment: See also https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physleta.2011.01.034.